# Adding a row with Column Spanning in Datagridview for windows form using C#

Tags: datagridview, datagridviewcolumn

I am trying to achieve this effect in windows forms where i can add a column with only one row i have looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16470860/make-some-of-datagrid-cells-span-multiple-columns) but its only for WPF not windows forms also saw another but for [asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6743044/insert-a-row-with-one-column-datagridview-c-sharp)

This is the effect I want to achieve [multi column row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/efUaA.png) on my Form

Comment: See [How to Merge DataGridViewCell in Winforms](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16774966/3773066).  It's referring particularly to merging cells between rows, but conceptually the idea is the same.  There are also a few things to try with row grouping: ([1](http://10tec.com/articles/datagridview-grouping-two-recipes.aspx), [2](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b54d2c92-6dbf-4f54-9e23-3a1303a20a93/row-grouping-in-datagridview-using-winforms?forum=winforms)).  See [also](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32133700/3773066).

Comment: I will try it out